# How to fix loop not working using execv and forks

Tags: c++

When running this program after the first iteration the program stops. This is because of execv function. What can I do so my loop still continues on until the user types quit.

I have tried creating a fork process before doing the execv in the child process but that does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    int rs;
    pid_t cpid;
    pid_t cpid2;
    rs = pipe(pipefd);
    char* args1[256];
    char* args2[256];
    if (rs < 0){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    char cmd1[256];
    char cmd2[256];
    char path1[10];
    char path2[10];
    while(true){
        cout << "Command 1";
        cin.getline(cmd1,256);
        cout << "command 2";
        cin.getline(cmd2,256);
        if (strcmp(cmd1,"quit") == 0)
            break;
        if (strcmp(cmd2,"quit") == 0)
            break;
        char *token;
        token = strtok(cmd1," ");
        int i=0;
        while(token != NULL){
            args1[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }
        args1[i] = NULL;
        token = strtok(cmd2," ");
        i = 0;
        while(token != NULL){
            args2[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }
        args2[i] = NULL;
        strcpy(path1,args1[0]);
        strcpy(path2,args2[0]);
        rs = fork();
        if (rs < 0){
            perror("Fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (rs == 0){//child process
            close(pipefd[1]);
            close(0);
            dup(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            rs = execvp(path2,args2);
            if (rs < 0){
                perror("execl");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else{//PARENT PROCESS
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(1);
            dup(pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            wait(&rs);  
            rs = execvp(path1,args1);   
            if (rs < 0){
                perror("execl");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

After outputting the answer the function should then ask the user for two more commands, This should go on until the user types in quit.

Comment: Why are you using C strings instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @Barmar would that fix the loop?

Comment: No, it was just a general comment.

Comment: You should only call `execvp()` in a child process if you want the parent to continue.

Comment: If you want to run two programs and keep running the original program, you need to fork twice.

Comment: @Barmar Where would i put the second fork i have tried a fork in the cild process

Comment: No, you put the first fork immediately after reading the command, followed by the existing code. Of course, you have several other major problems that will prevent you from correctly doing this. Such as the fact, as I'm sure you fully understand, each set of commands (once you get the loop working) needs its own pipe between the first and the shown program, but the shown code creates a pipe just once,and will attempt to use the same pipe with every pair of commands.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Im not sure i understand may you point me in the right direction on what you mean by after reading the command? What other problems will my cide have to use the loop correctly? Thank you for your help

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you saying i need the pipe operator in the loop? I have tried putting the fork right after getting the commands and if i enter ls and wc it out puts 0 0 0 and then on a new line 56 56 412

Comment: You are unlikely to make things work right by making random code changes, without fully understanding the complete consequences of each change. I'm not sure how I can make this more clear: after reading the command, an immediate fork, and the parent goes back to the beginning of the loop, meanwhile the child process does everything the shown code here already does. And, of course, fixing the pipe problem. Which is a separate but related issue (free clue: create the pipe after the first fork, in the first child process).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I guess I do not understand what you after the command. Do you mean the user enters commands or do you mean in the child process or parent process execvp calls? Thank you for you help

Comment: I mean "the user enters a command".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have put a fork there do I need to put a fork anywhere else in my program or should there only be one. So I put the pipe operator in the child process?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` is making your program exit.So remove it.
And you can put the possible exception creating code in `try {} catch {}` block.
In your case like this..

```
try{
rs = execvp(path1,args1);   
if (rs < 0){
    perror("execl");
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}catch(int y){
    continue;//here you can put your handling logic
}
```

By this you will get the desired output.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what your trying to do?

Comment: use try{}catch{} where code makes your program exit @hacobo

Comment: If `execvp` returns at all, something has gone wrong like there's no such executable, so it would be pointless for the child to continue.